# Excel: How to highlight highest value cell where duplicate in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a report containing a log of members details and any actions carried out on their account.

As it is a log, there are duplicate membership_numbers in column A. Column B is the action on account and Column C is the action_id.

How can I highlight the column with the latest action_id for each membership_number?

[image: Table screenshot]

Comment: How do you identify the "latest" action?  Is the latest action always as you've shown in the example; i.e. the latest is always the last, going down, in the list for any member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: final formatted table]

This can be accomplished with conditional formatting on the `TRUE` cells in latest_action. All these formulas are created within a table, see [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Excel-table-in-a-worksheet-E81AA349-B006-4F8A-9806-5AF9DF0AC664) if you're not sure how to make one, and [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E) for how I did the cell references.
My formulas in each column are:

- count: `=COUNTIF([membership_number],[@[membership_number]])`
- sub_rank: `=SUMPRODUCT(([membership_number]=[@[membership_number]])*([action_id]>[@[action_id]]))+1`
- latest_action: `=IF([@[sub_rank]]=1,TRUE,FALSE)`

With a some more work, I'm sure you could get rid of the helper columns and combine everything into just one formula hidden away in the conditional formatting. Otherwise, you can just use the conditional formula `=$F2=TRUE` and apply it to cells `$A$2:$F$9`.

Edit: I just realized that I highlighted the *first* action from each account. I've now modified my answer to highlight the *last* action from each account. this should work no matter what order the membership, as you can see in the image above which is sorted by action_details and the action_id is in no particular order. Before, I had the formula `=IF([@count]=[@[sub_rank]],TRUE,FALSE)` in latest_action and the following screenshot.

[image: first-action-highlighted]